# Python floating point fractions printing in binary issue

Tags: python, binary

I teach Python and showed my students how some decimal fractions in binary cannot be represented exactly

I showed the following Python program

```
INTEREST_RATE = .07
import struct
def binary(num):
    return ''.join('{:0>8b}'.format(c) for c in struct.pack('!f', 
                   num))

amount =10.00
interest = amount * INTEREST_RATE
roundInterest = round(interest,2)
print(interest,binary(interest))
print(roundInterest,"              ",binary(roundInterest))
print(.70,binary(.70))
if   interest == .70:
    print("not exact")
elif roundInterest == .70:
    print("better")
```

my question is from the output below, how can the variable interest and roundInterest have different values when printed but the same internal binary representation? (I even used another function to print the binary - IEEE754 and got the same results).  and yet with the if logic roundInterest amount compares exactly to .70 while the interest does not- I would assume something is different in the way the interest and roundInterest are stored:)

"0.7000000000000001 00111111001100110011001100110011"

"0.7                00111111001100110011001100110011"

"better"

I would expect the binary representation to be different for the rounded and unrounded amount.

Comment: You forget that you are generating the binary representation with some precision, in this case you are using `!f` which means you get the binary representation of the float C type, try using `!d` instead (double C type) and you'll see that you now get a different result for both.

Comment: Abdul you are a Godsend - thanks so much!  Since floats are stored as doubles in Python I thought I was missing some precision - not sure why the examples for Python printing binary of a float show it with a C type instead of a double C type - thanks again